# Magento 2 How to get custom field name 'location_id' aded to "customer_address_entity" at frontend, on order place after observer?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, customer, address

I have create one module which add 'location_id' in 'customer_address_entity' table. I also create one observer which called when order placed. Here i got the address id from order, Now i want to fetch the value which is set to 'location_id' on my observer from address id.

how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: From which model location_id is set?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\Hello\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class orderSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var addressFactory
     */
    protected $_addressFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory

    ) {
         $this->_addressFactory = $addressFactory;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $addressId = 111;
        $address = $this->_addressFactory->create()->load($addressId);
        echo "<pre>";print_r($address->getData());exit;
    }
}
```